# Adding node to kubernetes cluster gives failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml and no networks found in /etc/cni/net.d

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have a two node k8s cluster working.  I added another node to the cluster and the `sudo kubeadm join ...` command reported that the node had joined the cluster.  The new node is stuck in the NotReady state:

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
msi-ubuntu18       NotReady   <none>   29m    v1.19.0
tv                 Ready      master   131d   v1.18.6
ubuntu-18-extssd   Ready      <none>   131d   v1.17.4
```

The `journalctl -u kubelet` shows this error:

```
Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
  22039 server.go:198] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/var/l...
```

But the file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml exists and looks OK.

The `sudo systemctl status kubelet` shows a different error:

```
kubelet.go:2103] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plu
cni.go:239] Unable to update cni config: no networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
```

And there is no /etc/cni/ directory on the new node.  (The existing node has /etc/cni/net.d/ with calico files in it.)  If I run

`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.11/manifests/calico.yaml`

on the master again it doesn't solve the problem.  There is still no /etc/cni/ dir on the new node.

I must have missed a step when creating the new node.  How do I get the /etc/cni/ directory on the new node?  It's also puzzling that the `kubeadm join ...` command indicates success when the new node is stuck in NotReady.

Comment: Did you add [pod CIDR](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/quickstart) when you initialized your cluster? Could you try to install latest calico version, which is 3.16, and check if it works? Could you add output from `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to your question?

Comment: Yes: `sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else running into this problem, I was finally able to solve this by doing

```
kubectl delete -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.11/manifests/calico.yaml
```

followed by

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
```

There must have been some version incompatibility between version 3.11, which I had installed a few months ago and the new node.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran through a similar situation, but the proximate cause was at a higher level.

Basically I applied some Gatekeeper security policies to the `kube-system` namespace without recognizing I'd have to make exceptions for `kube-proxy` and `aws-node` (this was in EKS).

A couple examples from the kube event logs:

```
[denied by psp-pods-allowed-user-ranges] Container kube-proxy is attempting to run without a required securityContext/runAsGroup. Allowed runAsGroup: {"ranges": [{"max": 65535, "min": 1}], "rule": "MustRunAs"}
[denied by caps-constraints] container <kube-proxy> is not dropping all required capabilities. Container must drop all of ["ALL"]
[denied by psp-hostfs-constraints] HostPath volume {"name": "xtables-lock", "hostPath": {"path": "/run/xtables.lock", "type": "FileOrCreate"}} is not allowed, pod: kube-proxy-j5h2d. Allowed path: [{"pathPrefix": "/tmp", "readOnly": true}]
```

I didn't notice this for a solid month after I'd applied the changes; it only showed up after one of my EKS nodes restarted for some reason.

Posting here in hopes it might save somebody else the day I lost.

Answer (score -1):

I also encounter same situation when initialized cluster with pods cidr #kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.10.0.0/16

[image]

But, #kubectl get pods --all-namespaces command helped to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: How should get pods should fix an issue? Do you have even the slightest of ideas how Kubernetes works?